# .Net service crashing while Unzipping 12GB File

Tags: c#, .net, chilkat, .net-services

We are using a service which uses a third party library of Chilkat to unzip a large sized zip file.

It works fine with small sized file.
But in case of bigger size like 7GB or more then the causes service to crash with no further information except the below -

```
Faulting application name: Service.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xe39527e5
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x04891bbc
Faulting process id: 0x8d6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d99cf461b00da6
Faulting application path: "Path\Service.exe"
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 9fabcdd5-9043-4686-a072-c1216eb91e44
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: How is the **SSD **or **HDD** formatted you are running this on? **FAT32** for example can't handle files larger than 4GB. Same for some other formats. Also do you have enough space left?

Answer (score 1):

32-bit or 64-bit?

All Chilkat components have excellent status codes and detailed failure text that you can access when you detect a failure. So check for success and if you detect a failure, display the failure text.

**Success/Failure Return Values**
Methods that return a boolean always return True for success and False for failure. (ActiveX methods return 1 for success, 0 for failure. Objective-C methods return YES for success and NO for failure.) If a method returns a new instance of a Chilkat object, a NULL (or nil, null, 0, etc. depending on the programming language) is returned upon failure.

**LastErrorText**
The LastErrorText property is common to most Chilkat classes/objects in all programming languages. It provides detailed information about the last method called on an object instance. The LastErrorText is the first place to get more information about why a method failed or behaved unexpectedly. The LastErrorText will contain information even when a method call is successful.

Comment: 32-Bit. Also, For you information, We have 14 instances of our service with each service have 3 to 5 Threads. I am not sure if that is the reason behind the issue, because, when I am running the Unzipping code in a stand alone EXE manually it works properly. But when the same code runs in the service, it throws exception.